# OnClientClick event for keeping track of prints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to keep track of prints that are made for a page. The page has Print this page link. And the code for it is like below: This is written in .cs file as there are many conditions for displaying this. And i am appending here using String Builder.

```
sbOutput.AppendFormat("<td align=\"right\" valign=\"bottom\"><div style =\"float:right;text-align:right; valign:bottom;width:200px\"class=\"print_button notPrinted\"><a class=\"notPrinted\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.print();\">PRINT THIS COUPON </a><img src=\"images/print-icon-34x34.gif\" class=\"notPrinted\" align=\"absmiddle\" /></div> </td></tr></table>", couponid, Userid, locationid);
```

Do i have to use onclientclick or something else??

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: `Do i have to use onclientclick or something else??` For what exactly? To execute the code in the event handler, subscribe to the `Click` event.

Comment: I am trying to keep track of number of prints that are made for a page. I want to add to database everytime Print is clicked.

Comment: Then your question is missing some vital information, please update it with your exact requirements and intent on implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good option would be to write a Javascript function to enable Ajax call, so that you can send a request to server to record the print coomand.

`<a href="return RecordPrint();">PRINT THIS COUPON</a>`

function RecordPrint()
{

```
// Make a AJAX Call to your server Page to record Print Command.
// printRecorded : success from server

If(printRecorded)
{
  window.print();
}
```

return false;

}

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

since you seem to print on the client side only, you could do

```
<a href=\"counter.aspx\" onclick=\"window.print();\">PRINT THIS COUPON </a>
```

On the server side, implement the counter.aspx page to just count the request and quit silently. Make sure, the window.print() will return true - otherwise the link is not executed.

Comment: "On the server side, implement the counter.aspx page to just count the request and quit silently??"  Could you please explain more on this.

Comment: counter.aspx would be just an empty page (no controls). Every time it loads (in Page_Load) you increment the counter in the DB/sessio/application cache or whereever it is stored. After that you call Response.Clear() and Response.End()